# Automated replacement of the scm part properties of a pom

Tags: version-control, maven, migration

At the moment we're going to migrating all of our cvs projects to git. 
Our custom script is using the git converter and everything is fine. 
Now i would like to incorporate the automated replacement  of the scm part 
properties with the new values.

Is there a plugin similar to org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin but appling to the scm part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but it would be a trivial plugin to implement.

Just define search and replace patterns:

```
/**
 * @parameter expression="${project}"
 * @readonly
 */
private MavenProject project;

/**
 * @parameter expression="${searchPattern}"
 * @required
 */
private String searchPattern;


/**
 * @parameter expression="${replacePattern}"
 * @required
 */
private String replacePattern;

/**
 * @component
 */
private ModelWriter modelWriter;

public void execute(){
    final Model model = project.getModel();
    model.getScm().setConnection(
            model.getScm()
            .getConnection()
            .replaceFirst(searchPattern, replacePattern));
    // do the same for scm.getDeveloperConnection()

    modelWriter.write(
        new File(project.getBasedir(),"pom.xml"),
        Collections.<String,Object>emptyMap(), model);
}
```

Comment: thanks, works like a charm. I only changed one thing, i opted for project.getOriginalModel() instead. With getModel() my pom was replaced with something that looked like the effective pom.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no plugin for this kind of purpose. (May be someone else knows one?)